# How to get return of react hook into a component

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

According to React you are only supposed to call a hook inside of a function.

But at some point I suppose I will want to have the output of that hook inside a component calling that function.

So I am trying to do the following

```
class AreaOfInterestSelector extends Component<IProps> {
    render() {
        const areas: object = GetAreasOfInterest();
        console.log(areas);
        return <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.noSelectionMessage}
        </React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

and

```
const GetAreasOfInterest = () => {
    const [areas, setAreas] = useState({});
    const categoryApi = '//example.org/api/category';
    const getCategories = async () => {
        const data = await Axios.get(categoryApi);
        return data;
    }
    useEffect( () => {
        const data = getCategories();
        setAreas(data);
    });

    return areas;
}

export default GetAreasOfInterest;
```

but I end up getting the error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Checking my top level dependencies I don't have the mismatching versions or more than one copy, before going through everything and looking I figured I'd ask because I bet I have just made a silly mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to React you are only supposed to call a hook inside of a function **component**. You are using hooks inside a function, not a function component.

For it to be a component it should return an element, and use it as a component. So it would be like this (considering you are returning an element):

```
<GetAreasOfInterest/>
```